# jquery mobile popup - button not styling correctly with data-iconpos="notext", and other problems

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, popup, styling

I am making a mobile web app and am using jQuery Mobile. I have a navbar at the bottom and when you click the left button the popup shows correctly but the close button is not being styled correctly when i use `data-iconpos="notext"`. Here is my code:

```
    <div data-theme="j" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div id="navbar" data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="bottom">
            <ul>
                <li id="navbar-menu-button">
                    <a href="#navbar-popup-menu" data-transition="slideup" data-position-to="window" data-rel="popup" data-theme="j" data-icon="bars" data-overlay-theme="j" data-dismissible="false"></a>

                    <div id="navbar-popup-menu" data-role="popup" class="ui-content">
                        <a id="navbar-menu-close-button" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" title="Close" data-dismissible="false" class="ui-btn-right"></a> 
                        test info
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li id="navbar-info-button">
                    <a href="#navbar-popup-info" data-transition="slide" data-position-to="window" data-rel="popup" data-theme="j" data-icon="info"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see in `div#navbar-popup-menu` I have an `<a>` tag with the following attributes:
`data-role="button"`, `data-rel="back"`, `data-icon="delete"`, `data-iconpos="notext"`, `data-dismissible="false"`, and `class="ui-btn-right"`

everything is working except `data-iconpos="notext"` and `data-dismissible="false"`. There is still a box around the button icon which shouldn't be there and you can still click outside of the popup to close it. you can view a live demo here: [DEMO](http://fscatalog.foursquaregames.com)

any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure this out because i have other buttons that are working and nothing is different between them that could cause what's happening.

ALSO: The close button is not working

Comment: `data-dismissible="false"` should be added to popup div only. not the close button. remove it and try again.

Comment: also on your website `data-rel="close"`, it should be `back` as in your code above. Are you overriding jQM CSS (not theme)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/qLFJ6/ check this.

Comment: did what you suggested and the button works, an oversite on my part for sure, but the button still has the box around it which is not the desired behavior

Comment: if you remove `data-theme` from the button, does the same happen?

Comment: yes it does, still not sure whats going wrong

Comment: try it with your custom.css i'm afraid you have modified `.ui-btn` which is affect all buttons with `.ui-btn`.

Comment: i haven't modified `ui-btn` in custom.css and I have other buttons with the `data-iconpos="notext"` attribute that are working, see the top right and left corners of the page and the headers on the panels. they all have the `ui-btn` along with the notext attribute and are styling correctly

Comment: Ok, if you work without your custom.css what happens to the popup?

Comment: it breaks everything that uses custom.css and still doesn't solve the problem

Comment: there must be something conflicting with the button. because X button on panel looks fine. Try moving the popup div above navbar div.

Comment: that was it, i just had the div in the wrong place, add that solution as an answer and I'll accept it, i just assumed that because the navbar was the context for the popup div that it should be inside it, but i guess that's not the case

Comment: Finally..glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using jQuery Mobile Popup, the parent div of the popup div should be either `data-role=page` or `data-role=content`. Placing it somewhere else would conflict with other divs. Also, it won't work if placed outside `data-role=page`.

Unlike Dialog, it should be placed outside `data-role=page`.